# Basic question in C++

Tags: c++, stl, visual-c++

I am new to C++ and I have some confusion regarding this program. I am running this in Visual Studio 2008 as win32 console application.

```
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;
    #define PI 3.14
    int l=1;
    int x;
    void main()
    {
        do
        {
            cout << "choose 1";
            cout << "choose 2";
            cin >> x;
            switch(x)
            {
                case 1:
                    cout << "action 1";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    cout << "action 2";
                    break;
                default:
                    cout << "unknown command";
                    break;
            }
        } while (l=1)
    }
```

When I run this program and type anything else than 1 or 2, it is not displaying the default option in the switch. I am unable to figure out the problem. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: inlcude?  while(1=1) ??    Both these errors wouldn't even compile. Did you retype the source? Why not copy/paste it from your IDE?

Comment: This won't even compile since you do not declare x.

Comment: have you run it through the debugger yet? step though it one line at a time and check that it does what you expect

Comment: sorry for the typos. the program compiles but unable to display the default type.

Comment: I tried building the above in Visual Studio 2008 as a Win32 C++ project and got an handful of errors such as "'cout': undeclared identifier." ;)

Comment: Hpro: next time you ask something, add a bit more time on it to prepare and make sure the errors/typos are out first.   There is still one in:  while(l=1) should have a double = (so: l==1)

Answer (score 2):

This is a better first attempt, which does perform all three cases depending on the input. The original version you gave didn't even compile due to various errors.

I suggest you start from this one:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x;
    do
    {
        cout<<"choose 1 or 2: ";
        cin>>x;
        switch(x)
        {
            case 1:
                cout<<"action 1"<<endl;
                break;
            case 2:
                cout<<"action 2"<<endl;
                break;
            default:
                cout<<"unknown command"<<endl;
                break;
        }
    } while(1==1);
    return 0;
}
```

Here's a sample run:

```
choose 1 or 2: 1
action 1
choose 1 or 2: 2
action 2
choose 1 or 2: 3
unknown command
choose 1 or 2: ^C
```

There are still problems even with the fixed code such as when you enter a non-numeric. You really should be getting strings from standard input and checking them for validity before converting to a number.

To handle non-numerics, this would be a good start:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string x;
    do
    {
        cout<<"choose 1 or 2: ";
        cin>>x;
        if (!isdigit(x[0])) {
            cout<<"non-numeric command"<<endl;
        } else {
            switch(x[0])
            {
                case '1':
                    cout<<"action 1"<<endl;
                    break;
                case '2':
                    cout<<"action 2"<<endl;
                    break;
                default:
                    cout<<"unknown command"<<endl;
                    break;
           }
       }
    } while(1==1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This Works - only for int (if you type a char.. it will get messy)

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
#define PI 3.14 int l=1; void main() {  int x;
    do
    {
        cout<<"choose 1";
        cout<<"choose 2";
        cin>>x;
        switch(x)
        {
            case 1:
                cout<<"action 1";
                break;
            case 2:
                cout<<"action 2";
                break;
            default:
                cout<<"unknown command";
                break;
        }
    } while(1==1);
```

}

How to handle input:

```
// iostream_cin.cpp
// compile with: /EHsc
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int x;
   cout << "enter choice:";
   cin >> x;
   while (x < 1 || x > 4)
   {
      cout << "Invalid choice, try again:";
      cin >> x;
      // not a numeric character, probably
      // clear the failure and pull off the non-numeric character
      if (cin.fail())
      {
         cin.clear();
         char c;
         cin >> c;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: make x a char and than parse it's value or limit the input legnth
I've added something to the edit from msdn - how to handle cin errors:

Answer (score 0):

1. I cannot compile in my VS2008 unless I include  for the cin, cout to work.
2. After that it works fine - it prints 'unknown command' for values other than 1 and 2.

Comment: you mean for char values also? what happens if you give 'c' or any other alphabet?

Comment: Yes. Basically in C++, if you define a variable outside the main, they will be initialized. So in your case the variable 'x' should have been initialized to zero.

Now char input fails, however the value remains zero, so it should always hit the 'default' section of the switch.